# Compiling static c++ mysql connector from source with visual studio

Tags: mysql, cmake, mysql-connector

I want to link statically my small software to use mysql connector.

I'm trying to build it from source. So I have generated the visual studio solution using CMake.

I can build the mysqlcppconn project just fine (which is the dynamic version of it). But for the static version, mysqlcppconn-static, I get an error.

> Error 27  error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:/Program'

I don't really know what I missed, I can build the dynamic version without any issue but not the static one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio makes a distinction between paths that are in quotes, and paths that are not in quotes. (WHY!?) Paths without quotes must not have any spaces in them.

Somewhere in the project configuration for the static version of the library, the cmake generator has created a path without spaces.

Since visual studio's error information is shit, and does not tell you where this path is located, the easiest solution by far is to just move the source files to a location on your disk drive that does not have a space in it.